# How does AntiForgeryToken, specifically, 'match up' with a cookie?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, cookies, http-post, verification, antiforgerytoken

We have a web page, and it has a form on it. There is an antiforgerytoken added to this MVC page's form via the helper:

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
```

We realised today that we have the page cached, which we thought would be a massive issue, but multiple machines may submit the same form, even though they share the same verification token in the page's source!?

This is unexpected as far as I'm aware, I thought the idea was that the same verification token can be found in the cookie? I'm obviously misunderstanding the mechanism behind the token (both on the page and the amendment of a user's cookie).

**Can somebody explain to me how this page still works?** More specifically, how the server validates the form's post request.

I thought it was as simple as the server checking that the token string was identical to a token string found in the cookie.

NB: Caching is turned off for now fwiw, we're not 100% happy with caching a page with tokens on it now that we're a bit more clued up on it.

Comment: Do you mean you expect posting a cached form to fail, but it works instead?

Comment: Sorry @CodeCaster, I mustn't have been clear enough. Yes, I expect a cached form to fail. But it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> We realised today that we have the page cached, which we thought would be a massive issue, but multiple machines may submit the same form, even though they share the same verification token in the page's source!?

Yes, caching is a problem when it comes to anti-forgery tokens.  You have two choices:

1. Don't cache the form.
2. Use the `VaryByCustom` property of `OutputCache` to vary by the token itself.

I don't have code to hand with me, so I'll show you an example which is taken from [this](http://southworks.com/blog/2010/04/26/working-together-with-antiforgerytoken-and-outputcache-on-aspnet-mvc/) article:

> In order to avoid this issue you can use the VaryByCustom property on the OutputCache attribute:
>
> ```
> [OutputCache(
>   Location = OutputCacheLocation.ServerAndClient,
>   Duration = 600,
>   VaryByParam = "none",
>   VaryByCustom = "RequestVerificationTokenCookie")]
> public ActionResult Index()
> {
>   return new View();
> }
> ```
>
> And then program the rule on the global.asax‘s GetVaryByCustomString method:
>
> ```
> public override string GetVaryByCustomString(HttpContext context, string custom)
> {
>   if (custom.Equals("RequestVerificationTokenCookie", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
>   {
>     string verificationTokenCookieName =
>       context.Request.Cookies
>         .Cast<string>()
>         .FirstOrDefault(cn => cn.StartsWith("__requestverificationtoken", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
>     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(verificationTokenCookieName))
>     {
>       return context.Request.Cookies[verificationTokenCookieName].Value;
>     }
>   }
>   return base.GetVaryByCustomString(context, custom);
> }
> ```

### Edit per comments

The reason it works is because it's only comparing the value of the cookie to the value of the generated hidden field on the form.  There isn't a list of tokens maintained on the server, ready to be validated, if you thought it might work that way.  That means, as far as the client is concerned, despite the generation of the form being cached on the server, the client is still receiving a 'new' form and, consequently, a cookie to go along with that, so the comparison won't fail.

Comment: That it's not supposed to work and how to disable cacahing with a custom filter or by other means is already answered in plenty of questions on SO (just search "mvc antiforgerytoken caching"). I think OP's problem is that it _does_ work, despite everyone saying it shouldn't.

Comment: @CodeCaster Ah, I might have misunderstood the problem then.  I'll leave this here and see what he replies with first before deleting.

Comment: Apologies John, I probably wasn't clear enough. +1 either way, thanks a lot for the effort.

Comment: @JayMee No need to apologise. CodeCaster figured it out, so I think it's just down to my weekend brain not kicking in. :)

Comment: @JohnH - I see (I think). So upon the server serving the same form (i.e. the cached form with somebody else's token in a hidden field), the server will also set the 2nd user's cooke to this 'shared token' value? So all users will have the same token, but it's fine - because all users will have the same token value also written to their cookie? If this is the case, why is caching such a bad thing? Thanks again, appreciate it's weekend and supposed to be people's time off.

Comment: @JayMee Aside from the fact that I never liked the idea of clients 'sharing' validation tokens, which I'm not entirely sure if it would create a problem or not so I default to deciding not to use it, there is one scenario I can think of.  Let's say a user fills out a form and submits it but with errors.  At this point, the token has been updated.  If the user now hits the back button (which still happens an awful lot), the form is likely cached in their browser, but the cookie has been updated, causing token errors on resubmission.

Comment: @JayMee However, this scenario depends on one of two things: either client-side validation not being enabled, or perhaps you have validation that must occur on the server-side.  With the enterprise-level web applications I help develop at work, there's a lot of complexity there, so we just prefer not to take the chance either way, but, unless there's a better reason to do so out there, that's just our preference.

Comment: How would that `GetVaryByCustomString` help to avoid the problem?! It does not generate any unique string but returns a cookie present in the request.